# Python でエラー: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python

DBの初期化部分でエラーとなってしまっているのですが、なぜエラーとなってしまうのか分かりません。

何回も、見直し、書き直しをしても解決できない状況です。
どなかた原因・解決方法をご教示ください。

```
def __init__(self, title, body, date):
```

app.py実行時のエラーメッセージ

```
  File "C:\work\dev\FLASK\CURD\app.py", line 32
    def __init__(self, title, body, date):
                                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecretkey'
URI = 'sqlite:///note.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = URI
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()


class Note(db.Model):
     __tablename__='notes'
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     title = db.Column(db.String(140))
     body = db.Column(db.String(300))
     date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Tokyo')))

    def __init__(self, title, body, date): # ここでエラーとなります
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.date = date

@app.route('/')
def index():
    title = '一覧画面'
    return render_template('index.html', title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class Note(db.Model):`の行と`def __init__(self, title, body, date):`の行の間のインデントが空白1桁だけ多いからでしょう。
その部分のインデントの空白を1桁削れば動作すると思われます。

```
class Note(db.Model):
     __tablename__='notes' #### ここから↓
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     title = db.Column(db.String(140))
     body = db.Column(db.String(300))
     date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now(timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))) #### ここまで↑

    def __init__(self, title, body, date): # ここでエラーとります
        self.title = title
        self.body = body
        self.date = date
```